Looking for free software to recognize facial expressions
I'm looking for a free and preferably open-source software that not only recognizes faces on a picture but also is able to classify the facial expressions.
I prefer open-source over quality, to an extend.
My favorite language is java, but I will learn about anything. I guess Python is nowadays hyped to do things like that.
I would prefer an open-source tool, because I would like to have a look at the internals, to learn about AI "hands on". Online-recognition is a no-go (I'm quite paranoid). A tool that recognizes faces, without interpreting facial expressions, would be a nice add-on.

Must it work offline? Are you OK with relying on a non open source gratis API? For instance, with Google Vision AI the first 1000 units used each month are free.

Your question is great, just tell us whether you are looking for a library (you mention programming languages) or a end-user-facing tool. Thanks!

@NicolasRaoul I would prefer an open-source tool, because I would like to have a look at the internals, to learn about AI "hands on". Online-recognition is a no-go (I'm quite paranoid). A tool that recognizes faces, without interpreting facial expressions, would be a nice add-on.

Thanks for the details! Please add the details to the question text itself, as comments will get deleted.
